# Fetched comparison data from Sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have below mentioned data base:

```
ID  TFD1    Date         CCA
D-1 123     25-01-2017   AA
D-2 123     24-01-2017   BA
D-3 123     27-01-2017   BB
D-4 456     15-01-2017   AA
D-5 456     13-01-2017   BS
D-6 789     11-01-2017   AA
```

I want to fetch those `ID`, `TFD1`, `Date` and `CCA` where there are at least one value corresponding to `TFD1` is `AA` and all the other old value corresponding to `TFD1` is other than `AA`.

I want to create the output sorted by oldest to newest.

Required Output:

```
ID  TFD1    Date         CCA
D-6 789     11-01-2017   AA
D-1 123     24-01-2017   BA
D-2 123     25-01-2017   AA
D-4 456     13-01-2017   BS
D-5 456     15-01-2017   AA
```

Comment: Your result set doesn't match your description.  How does `D-6` end up in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the "A"s that matter you can use:

```
select t.*
from t
where (t.cca = 'A' and
       not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.tfd1 = t.tfd1 and t.cca = 'A')
      ) ;
```

From this you can get everything before this date for each `tfd1`:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select t.*
      from t
      where (t.cca = 'A' and
             not exists (select 1
                         from t t2
                         where t2.tfd1 = t.tfd1 and t.cca = 'A' and t2.date < t1.date
                        )
            )
     ) tt
     on t.tfd1 = tt.tfd1 and t.date <= tt.date;
```